# My code compiles fine in Cygwin on windows 7 but fails in Linux due to case-sensitivity

Tags: c++, cygwin, cross-platform

I am compiling a code which has some case-insensitive includes (For example let's say there is a file named `SRS.h` but in one of the source file which needs to be compiled it is included as `#include <srs.h>`). When I compile such files in Cygwin 64 on Windows 7 they compile fine but in CentOS it's an error (file not found). How can I achieve the centOS like behavior in Cygwin on Windows 7?

Comment: Match the case of the files!?

Comment: Is `CentOS` setup to find the custom includes as system includes?

Comment: You should fix all the includes to use correct case.

Comment: Only windows ignores casing. Stick to correct casing

Comment: I think Sajal's question is how he can find out - on a windows machine - which includes have the wrong capitalization. I think that is a valid question.

Comment: When you say "compile such files in Cygwin 64", which compiler are you using?

Comment: @MartinBonner - I am using gcc (GCC) 5.4.0.

Comment: I think this is a problem of "how do I make cygwin case sensitive" in general.  I would google for that.

Comment: @MikeMB - That's exactly what I want to know. I want my Cygwin to throw same errors as CentOS while compiling my code. Thanks MikeMB for clarifying.